# What is a batch?

Tags: sql, t-sql

In Transact-SQL, a batch is a set of SQL statements submitted together and executed as a group, one after the other. Batches can be stored in command files.

Is an *.sql file containing several SQL statements considered a batch? What else do we consider a batch?

Comment: Is this question only related to tsql? Smells a bit like homework...

Comment: Stack needs a tag called "batch-tsql" .

Comment: @djangofan someone with +1500 rep needs to create the 'batch-tsql' tag first.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is an *.sql file containing several sql statements considered a batch?

Sort of. A `*.sql` file is often a batch, but it could also contain several batches. You delimit separate batches via a batch separator. You might need multiple batches in a file because some statements (especially certain `ALTER` commands) can only be executed once per batch. This can make things like performing `ALTER`s in a loop tricky, because certain statement (`SET`) will apply through the end of a batch, and because Sql Server will have an implicit transaction which commits at the end of each batch.

Another trick here is how you separate individual batches in a file/document. In 99% of Sql Server tools, the batch separator is "`GO`".  However, this is something that is configurable by the tool. It's not part of the SQL language itself, and therefore you can run into the odd person now and then who uses something else, or get confused that SQL Server complains if you send it a "GO" command directly.

Comment: 1) I’m not sure I understand why having batches is a good thing ( I realize certain statements can only be executed once per a batch, but if batches didn’t exist, then we wouldn’t have that problem ), thus why did Sql server development team thought that it would be a good idea to introduce batches?!
2) Besides the fact that certain statements can only be executed once per a batch, are there any other reasons why we would put a bunch of statements into several different batches instead of putting them all into a single batch?

Comment: Certain other statements (SET options) will apply until the end of the batch.

Comment: Old now, but for the idea that we wouldn't have the problem if batches didn't exist, that's just not true. If batches didn't exist, you'd have to send those statements in separate sessions for files. No one did extra work to make statements like `ALTER` break if you use more than one in the same batch just because. That would be silly. Rather, when implementing `ALTER` it turned out there are some extra concerns to be aware of, and they haven't yet put in the extra effort required to make them work safely in the same batch.

Answer (score 6):

Batches are not part of TSQL, they are a function of the SQL Management Studio Editor.  So, for example, you cannot submit an ADO.NET command object with "GO" as part of your command text.

The batch marker - "GO" tells the query editor to submit the SQL up to that point before proceeding during execution.

It is possible to configure the query editor to use a different batch marker beside "GO", but this would just confuse the heck out of people.

Comment: They are part of TSQL. You can send a batch with multiple commands in ADO.NET, too.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken.  Here's an MSDN TSQL reference page on the GO command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Comment: On second thought, I see what you mean.  The batch definition in the original question is correct, and batches affect the execution of TSQL statements.

Comment: I know I did have trouble running "Go" from a Visual Studio app, perhaps in C#.

Answer (score 5):

from Books online

> CREATE DEFAULT, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE RULE, CREATE SCHEMA, CREATE TRIGGER, and CREATE VIEW statements cannot be combined with other statements in a batch. The CREATE statement must start the batch. All other statements that follow in that batch will be interpreted as part of the definition of the first CREATE statement.
>
> A table cannot be changed and then the new columns referenced in the same batch.

From this you might infer that multiple batches are needed to ensure the database structure changes have taken effect before you try to use them.