# Setting SQL Server compatibility level based on the server in script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

When I try to set the compatibility level for SQL Server in a script it errors out for SQL Server 2008. I want this script to be same to executed against all the servers - 2008, 2012 or 2014 which we currently support.

```
-- Set database compatibility --
IF SUBSTRING(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR),1 ,2) >= 11
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('sql server 12 and above', 10, 1)

    ALTER DATABASE JJAI_TESTDB SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('sql server 2008',10, 1)

    ALTER DATABASE JJAI_TESTDB SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
END
GO
```

Below is the error:

```
Msg 15048, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Valid values of the database compatibility level are 80, 90, or 100.
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It looks like the error is happening on the 1st alter statement. What product version do you get if you do a print with the if criteria?

Comment: My product version is 2008. So the script is actually not executing, but failing in the compilation itself or pre-processing whichever happens

Comment: Since `ALTER DATABASE` changes the way statements are processed, it needs to be executed in a separate batch. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1703916/92546) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to do it by executing the alter statement within an execute statement like below.

```
/* Set database compatibility */
IF SUBSTRING(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR),1 ,2) >= 11
    EXECUTE ('ALTER DATABASE $(DATABASENAME) SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110')
ELSE
    EXECUTE ('ALTER DATABASE $(DATABASENAME) SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100')
GO
```